# Version control with RStudio: how to compare and modify files from multiple users

Tags: r, version-control, rstudio

I am new to the use of version control in RStudio. I would like to know what is the optimal way to do this:

- I have a R project, and I can give one version of the project to a coworker.
- Then he will modify some files (and me too).
- When he gives the folder back to me, is there is simple way to compare two files and decide which which lines go to the final version?

Answer (score 1):

The usual workflow for comparing files using builtin Rstudio is through version control tools such as git or subversion.

Your process is more "I give you the content of the project folder, make whatever you want and give it back to me" then "you want to know what have changed between your copy and his".

Rstudio won't help you in this case. You'd better use merge tools such as meld, winmerge, .. that will spot the differences between files and their content and allow you to copy changes in either way (from you to him or him to you)

Comment: Adding to @Billy34 answer, for more details on how to use Git, you can read the online version of the [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) book. In RStudio, this means setting up a project in a common git or Github repository, and having each team member pull the latest content from the repository, and periodically push their content back to the main repository. Also as noted, you'll need tools to spot differences between files and their content.